# C++ uniform initialization in C arrays and structs

Tags: c++, c++11, uniform-initialization

I've seen some old code that looks like this: `char foo[100] = { 0 };`. Something similar happens with structs, like so: `STRUCT st = { 0 };`. The intention in both cases is clear, namely to zero-initialize the respective variables. As such, `char foo[100] {};` and `STRUCT st {};` would have been more idiomatic.

My question is: should the code with `<variable> = { 0 }` be expected to achieve the same outcome? I've tested this with release-build binaries and the elements appear to be zero-initialized, but is this guaranteed by the standard? It seems to me that `<variable> = { 0 }` should only guarantee for the first element of the variable (array element or struct member) to be zero.

Also, what behavior is indicated by the similar declarations `char foo[100] = {};` and `STRUCT st = {}`?

(Motivation behind this question is that I'd change all the declarations to the idiomatic form, but if there is no guarantee of zero-initialization then the issue is something more serious and worth opening a ticket over.)

Comment: Please read about [*aggregate* initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) and [*value* initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

Comment: What is `STRUCT`?

Comment: @juanchopanza: a C-struct of any kind

Comment: there is no such thing as idiomatic form.. `= { 0 }` was the only form of initialization allowed in C, C++11 allows empty braced list and uniform initialization `struct s {};` Note that there are underwater reefs with its use, uniform initialization may do not what you expect with non-trivial classes that accept `initializer_list`. E.g. `vector<int>  v {3};` creates vector containing one element with value of 3.

Comment: Also, the meaning of { 0 } is subtly different to your understanding. Under the old "C" rules, this initialises the first members to the values given, then zeros any other members. I.e. { 1 } does not set all members to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems to me that `<variable> = { 0 }` should only guarantee for the first element of the variable (array element or struct member) to be zero.

That syntax, for POD types, is the same as `<variable> = {};`

Anything that is not explicitly specified is initialized to zero. Use of `<variable> = { somve_value }` makes a difference only when `some_value` is other than zero.

Even though the same syntax can be used for non-POD types, the elements that are of non-POD type that are not explicitly initialized are initialized using their default constructors.

From [8.5.1 Aggregates/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init.aggr#7):

> If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be initialized from an empty initializer list  ([[dcl.init.list]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init.list)). [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> struct S { int a; const char* b; int c; };
> S ss = { 1, "asdf" };
> ```
>
> initializes `ss.a` with `1`, `ss.b` with `"asdf"`, and `ss.c` with the value of an expression of the form `int()`, that is, `0`.  — *end example* ]

Comment: Worth pointing out that the syntax is equivalent for non-POD types too.